# Selenium + C# How to switch another Tab of Firefox when click a link and it will open in another tab?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm using SeleniumRC with C#, How to switch another Tab of Firefox when click a link and it will open in another tab?
Some one please help me out, in this functionality. The goal is simple to move another opened tab to search some text.

This code is in C#

```
public void TheUntitledTest()
{
    selenium.Open("/abc/static/index.html");
    // selenium.WindowFocus();
    selenium.Click("link=Privacy Statement");
    selenium.WaitForPopUp("hello world - Mozilla Firefox", "20000");
    selenium.SelectPopUp("hello world - Mozilla Firefox");
    selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
    for (int second = 0; ; second++)
    {
        if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
        try
        {
            if (selenium.IsTextPresent("welcome")) break;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium.SelectWindow

Answer (score 0):

See this solution for similar question of opening a new tab with WebDriver. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9122450/648076

It seems it is not supported out of the box but you can execute javascript that tries to open new tab for you.