# Not able to identify tab in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

[image]

Below is code for tab - account.This is third tab.
I have to go on tab but I am not able to identify

```
    <td class="buttons" nowrap="nowrap" title="Shows data of bank account"
 onclick="document.forms[0].debbuttonpressed.value='CONTO';EmptyHiddenButtonValues('CONTO');;
document.forms[0].submit();" style="background-image:url(/images/reiter_unchecked_middle.gif);
background-repeat:repeat-x;cursor:pointer;" heigth="21">Account</td>
```

Comment: can you provide the link to full HTML? From this snippet is hard to guess where in DOM the Account is

Comment: and please explain what you mean by "tab". and provide the code you are trying to identify the "tab".

Comment: Answer found here:

Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421988/webdriver-open-new-tab

Comment: i have attached image for tab structure

Comment: Seems like its part of the HTML page. Then the tab should have some ID - i mean the "Billing address." We all do too much guess work here. Can you provide link to the actual application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//td[text()='Account']
```

OR

```
//td[@title='Shows data of bank account']
```

This is working solution for above scenario