# Opening a URL in a new tab using selenium-webdriver in IE

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer-9, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium-webdriver to automate browser. I need to open a url in a new tab in selenium. I am currently able to open a new tab using

```
driver.find_element(:css,'body').send_keys [:control,'t']
```

But when i try to open an url in the opened tab using `driver.get` it does not work in ie9. It opens in the previous tab itself. This works fine in chrome and firefox, but not in ie9. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

There is no current way to do so in WebDriver, but there is a sort of a hack that allows you to do it by injecting an anchor tag with the URL as the src into the DOM and telling WebDriver to click it.

You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949850/1221475) as I have detailed how to do it in Ruby (the previous example was in Java)