# Selenium and new tab

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

How i can open link on new tab in selenium webdriver ( firefox ) ?

```
<a href='/test' id='test'>Link</a>

driver.find_element_by_id('test').click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your best bet at the moment is to inject an anchor tag into the page. You'll need to adapt this to python, but it should be relatively straight forward: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9122450/39843

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.crm.qa.BaseTest;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class NewTabChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
                "C:/Users/sunil/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 (2)/chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();//open browser
        driver.manage().window().maximize();//browser maximize
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");//open google 

        //open new tab 
        for(int i = 0; i<=1;i++){
        Robot rob = new Robot();
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        ArrayList<String> tabs1 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
        //Switch to new tab
        driver.switchTo().window((String) tabs1.get(i));
    }
        //open facebook
        driver.get("http://facebook.com");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```