# Open a link in new tab with Splinter

Tags: python, splinter

I'm using Splinter to test Webpages.
Is there a way to easily open a Link in a new Tab (something like `link.middle_click()`)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a procedure to work around the problem with selenium:
https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903

For what I can find this can not "easily" done. I'll refer you the following questions which states some workarounds but there's no easy solution.
- [WebDriver open new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421988/webdriver-open-new-tab)
- [How to open a new window or tab in webdriver (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682350/how-to-open-a-new-window-or-tab-in-webdriver-python)

Comment: It is better to include the content of the gist. They can be deleted by the owner.

Answer (score 1):

This opens a new tab

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser.driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
```

Then you can switch between tabe and do what you want using:

http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/browser.html#managing-windows

Answer (score 0):

**HTML and Python/Splinter Combination**

First, create a html file with links you want to open in new tabs (e.g. links.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Links</h2>
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.youtube.com">youtube</a>
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" ref="https://www.facebook.com">facebook</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Second, open the previous html file, and call the links by python/splinter.

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('chrome')
browser.driver.maximize_window()
browser.visit('c:\\links.html')
elements = browser.find_by_tag("a")
for element in elements:
    element.click()
    browser.windows.current = browser.windows[0]
```