# python-webdriver throws ElementNotVisibleException when running Internet Explorer in windows 2008 server

Tags: python, windows, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I am running my python-webdriver test cases on different platforms. Currently i am encountering an error in Windows 2008 Server using InternetExplorer. Here are the details of my test environment:

OS: Windows 2008 Server SP1
python bindings: selenium version 2.35
IEServerDriver version 2.35 (latest)

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("action_button").click()
```

Everything is fine up until the code above is executed. An error "ElementNotVisibleException: Message: "The point at which the driver is attempting to click on the element was not scrolled into the viewport." will display.

But When i execute the code in Internet explorer of Windows 7, the problem does **not** occur.

I tried using ActionChain as stated in "[Selenium JavascriptExecutor on IE9 results in 'element was not scrolled into the viewport' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252837/selenium-javascriptexecutor-on-ie9-results-in-element-was-not-scrolled-into-the)" but the problem still exist.

Question:

Is there a difference between Internet Explorer of Windows 7 and Windows 2008?

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: are they different versions of IE ?

Comment: windows 2008 is using IE8 8.0.6001.18928 while windows 7 is IE8 8.0.7600.16385. yeah, i guess they differ in build version :/

Comment: again, i tested the script in another machine windows 2008 Server R2 with IE identical to windows 7. The problem stills occur in windows 2008 server >_<

Comment: Can you paste the entire html code ?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh i'm sorry but i cannot share the whole html code as i am forbidden to share.

here is a snipplet to where the cause of the error:
<input type="button" class="regular" id="actions" name="actions" value="Actions ▼" onclick="toggleDropdown();">

Comment: what confuses me is that this button exist on different pages but the problem does not occur on those pages.

Comment: Catch the exception and try doing the same thing again. Let me know if it works