# unable to open new tab in FIreFox,, Help me finding the solution

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, tabs

unable to open new tab in FireFox,, Help me finding the solution.... or suggest me is it possible or not using Selenium Web Driver - Java ?

I tried many ways but failed. please help me solving this problem..

Comment: [Specific answer that works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9122450/646634) from the marked duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

Try Ctrl + T and see if that helps.

Comment: Note the `selenium` tag.