# Open link in new tab

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried the code below for opening a link in new tab. It is opening a tab but the focus remains in the old tab itself.

```
Actions act= new Actions(driver);
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Selenium"));
act.contextClick(element).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

How to change focus to new tab?

Comment: Can you able to visualize the newly opened tab?

Comment: If so, try switch windows concepts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421988/webdriver-open-new-tab#9122450
here is your answer

Comment: Ya I am able to view the newly opened tab.