# Selenium operation in different tab (Python or C++)

Tags: javascript, python, c++, selenium, tabs

I have an issue with Selenium.
I have a scenario:

1. Users opens a browser via script:

   ```
   driver = webdriver.Firefox()
   driver.get ("some_startpage")
   ```
2. Then USER opens a new tab (the person clicks, it is done not by selenium, but manually).

I want to change one element on page in second tab, but my webdriver is focused on the first tab.

I've tried with `driver.getWindowHandles()` to change webdriver focus, but it shows me only one handle (to the main window), and I cannot switch context to the second tab.

- `webdriver.tittle` shows the title of the second tab and
- `webdriver.current_url` shows the url of the first tab

But thats normall. I've read that selenium doesn't support tabs in browser.

My questions:

- Is there any work around (mayby js?) to operate on elements on second (third, fourth...) tab in browser?
- I don't want to open new browser window, and human must manually open tab, it can't be done via selenium.

Comment: Do you want to open a new tab with your code?

Comment: No Kasisnu, user personally opens a new tab. I want to integrate with elements(for example via js) in new tab. But my selenium driver is focused on the different tab (that is opened via webdriver).

Comment: You're very likely to be out of luck. If the user were to open a new instance of the browser manually, would you expect the driver to be able to drive it (hint: the answer is "no")? Now consider that a new manually opened tab is indistinguishable from a new browser instance from WebDriver's perspective. This, I would expect the driver to be unable to recognize a manually opened tab.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421988/webdriver-open-new-tab Maybe you could try something like this.

Comment: @JimEvans but if there is a way to get the new tab handle for example exploring(enumerating) the opened windows in operating systems and send that handle to driver.switchTo().window(winHandle).

Comment: Do not confuse the overloaded term "window handle" here. The "handle" used by WebDriver is **not** the Windows (or other operating system) window handle. Rather, it is simply a unique string the driver assigns to the window for purposes of identification. If WebDriver doesn't recognize the tab, it won't have a "handle" to use with `switchTo().window()`.