# Selenium-WebDriver: Open links in the same IE window

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to emulate clicking in my application using Selenium Webdriver and IE 8. I am trying to open a link in the same window so that the browser session and proxy settings are preserved.

Could someone suggest a way to do this with Selenium on IE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually open the Link in New Tab you can achieve this by performing *Context Click* on the Link and selecting *'Open in new Tab'* option. Below is the implementation in *Selenium web-driver* with *Java* binding.

```
Actions newTab= new Actions(driver);
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the element"));

//Open the link in new window
newTab.contextClick(link).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Web-driver handles new tab in the same way to that of new window. You will have to switch to new open tab by its window name.

```
driver.switchTo().window(windowName);
```

You can keep track of window-names which will help you to easily navigate between tabs.

Comment: Rupesh, thanks for your reply. I think WebDriver does not support opening links in new tabs currently. If you know the url there are some workarounds using which a new tab can be opened - [WebDriver open new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421988/webdriver-open-new-tab).

But you cant do it with a click() or contextClick(). The above code opens a new window in IE 8 for me. Does it work for you?