# Opening Selenium WebDriver In Current Open Session

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

Is there a way to have selenium WebDriver open a new window or tab in the same session that I have been using? I am trying to skip a salesforce login process that requires a phone verification, and think that this is the only way to do it. For some reason the cookies don't work to bypass the phone verification log-in.

Comment: Please share what you have coded so far. Does it have to be on different windows/ tabs, or can it be on the same one, but going to different urls each time?

Answer (score -1):

I believe this has already been solved! Check out this answer:

[WebDriver open new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421988/webdriver-open-new-tab?rq=1)

Cheers!

Comment: Doesn't that open a new tab based on the new WebDriver Instance? I'm looking for somthing that will start a new driver instance based on a current session such as the one I'm typing in right now.